# Running ./configure with -Wall leads to libraries not being found

Tags: c, autotools, automake

I'd like to use `-Wall` and `-Werror` as flags for gcc in an autotools project, but I don't want to put them in my configure.ac.

As such, I tried using `./configure CFLAGS='-Wall -Werror'`, only to get an error from one of my `AC_SEARCH_LIBS` macro calls:

```
AC_SEARCH_LIBS([pow], [m], , AC_MSG_ERROR([Could not find standard math library.]))
```

Resulting error when running configure with the `CFLAGS` added:

```
configure: error: Could not find standard math library.
```

What am I doing wrong here? Configuration works fine without the CFLAGS variable set.

Comment: Check your config log file for the output that came from it trying to run that step.  You'll see what the error was and can probably fix it.

Comment: The log file tells me: `error: conflicting types for built-in function 'pow' [-Werror]`, after trying to compile conftest.c. Removing -Werror from the CFLAGS gets rid of the issue, but that's not really any use to me.

Comment: http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.sysutils.autoconf.patches/5791

Comment: So fix the prototype to match in whatever hike generates it, and then try again.

Comment: @Carl You cannot do that.  This is a known issue; the tests that autoconf uses typically compile with warnings, and elevating warnings to errors via -Werror will cause the tests to fail.  A reasonable way to deal with this (if using automake) is to conditionally add the flags to `AM_CFLAGS` (the condition being a configure time check that `CC` accepts the flags).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you now know, elevating the compile warnings to errors confuses `./configure`.

What you can do is pass custom `CFLAGS` at `make` time:

```
$ ./configure
$ make CFLAGS='-O2 -g -Wall -Wextra -Werror'
```

The other option is William Pursell's approach: add an option to `./configure` to turn on `-Werror` if supported:

(configure.ac)

```
AC_ARG_ENABLE([werror],
              [AS_HELP_STRING([--enable-werror], [Use -Werror @<:@no@:>@])],
              [:],
              [enable_werror=no])
AM_CONDITIONAL([ENABLE_WERROR], [test "$enable_werror" = yes])
```

(Makefile.am)

```
if ENABLE_WERROR
AM_CFLAGS += -Werror
endif
```